# (113) No route to host on CentOS 6.2 (64bits)

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, centos6

Maybe this is a silly question but since I'm not a sysadmin I could not find a solution for this problem:

I made a clean installation of CentOS 6.2 (64bits) and I didn't change any configuration after that, I started Apache (as root) with

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

If I navigate to `localhost` I get a correct response from my server but if I try to navigate through my network IP (172.16.8.59) I get an error:

```
(113) No route to host
```

I google the error and everything points to the squid configuration as far as I read but not sure because I don't even have the squid service installed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the default firewall rules enabled you will not be able to access Apache without some additional configuration.  The simplest solution is to run the `system-config-firewall` tool and check the 'WWW (HTTP)` checkbox.

You can also disable the firewall temporarily by running:

```
service iptables stop
```

And you can disable the firewall permanently by follow the previous command with:

```
chkconfig iptables off
```